# Get pattern of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, javafx

I have a combo box with list of the current date with a different format. When the user selected the format, the current date with the selected format will be display. I need to save the selected pattern of the date in a file. I look everywhere and I can't find a specific answer for my problem. Is there a way to get the specific pattern of a date in java?

Comment: Still how will you differentiate the dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy if the date is 04/04/2016.

Comment: It depends on the pattern that was selected from the combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toPattern()):

```
public String toPattern()
Returns a pattern string describing this date format.
```

Answer (score 0):

When user select date-format bring that format here and pass , like "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" and display like that:

```
 SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(<Pass_here_your_date_format);
    Date date = new Date();
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(strDate);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: Sorry. But it seems like you don't understand my question. Thanks anyway.